# ConTeXt : set conversion set for enumeration

Tags: context

I am trying to learn how to use enumerations. I tried to set a numbering set, following this page of the wiki, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve without redefining all counters ?

```
\definestructureconversionset[myconversion][n, a, a, a][n]

\defineenumeration[test]

\setupenumeration[test]
                 [headstyle=bold,style=normal,
                   indenting=never, indentnext=no, margin=-0.5mm,
                   alternative=hanging, distance=0pt,
                   width=6mm, stopper={.}, text={},
                   before={\blank[none]},
                   prefixconversionset=myconversion]

\starttext

\test bla
\subtest ploup
\test bla

\stoptext
```

Thank you in advance.

## EDIT

After Metafox's intervention, I had the correct behavior with the previous MWE, but not with my real environment. The sole definition of the complete enumeration is already not behaving correctly. Here is a more complete MWE :

```
\definestructureconversionset[myconversion][n,n,a,a][n]

\defineenumeration[question]

\setupenumeration[question][headstyle=bold,style=normal,
  indenting=never, indentnext=no, margin=-0.5mm,
  alternative=hanging, distance=0pt,
  width=4mm, stopper={.}, text={},
  before={\blank[none]},
  numberconversionset=myconversion
]
\setupenumeration[subquestion][headstyle=bold,style=normal,
  indenting=never, indentnext=no, margin=-0.5mm,
  alternative=hanging, distance=0pt,
  width=6mm, stopper={.}, text={},
  before={\blank[none]},
  numberconversionset=myconversion
]
\setupenumeration[subsubquestion][headstyle=sl,style=normal,
  indenting=never, indentnext=no, margin=-0.5mm,
  alternative=hanging, distance=0pt,
  width=8mm, stopper={)}, text={},
  before={\blank[none]},
  numberconversionset=myconversion
]
\setupenumeration[subsubsubquestion][headstyle=sl,style=normal,
  indenting=never, indentnext=no, margin=-0.5mm,
  alternative=hanging, distance=0pt,
  width=11mm, stopper={)}, text={},
  before={\blank[none]},
  numberconversionset=myconversion
]

\def\doTA[#1]{
  \doifsomethingelse{#1}
    {
      \nextquestion
      \blank[big]\noindenting
      {\rm\bfb\convertedcounter[question][numberconversion=R]. #1}
      \blank[small,samepage]
    }
    {
      \question
    }
}

\def\doTB[#1]{
  \doifsomethingelse{#1}
    {
      \nextsubquestion
      \blank[small]\noindenting
      {\hskip 1cm {\rm\bfa\convertedcounter[question]. #1}}
      \blank[small,samepage]
    }
    {
      \subquestion
    }
}

\def\doTC[#1]{
  \doifsomethingelse{#1}
    {
      \nextsubsubquestion
      \blank[big]\noindenting
      {\hskip 1cm \sl\convertedcounter[question]) #1}
      \blank[small,samepage]
    }
    {
      \subsubquestion
    }
}

\def\doTD[#1]{
  \doifsomethingelse{#1}
    {
      \nextsubsubquestion
      \blank[big]\noindenting
      {\hskip 1cm \sl\convertedcounter[question][numberconversion=n]. #1}
      \blank[small,samepage]
    }
    {
      \subsubsubquestion
    }
}


\def\TA{\dosingleempty\doTA}
\def\TB{\dosingleempty\doTB}
\def\TC{\dosingleempty\doTC}
\def\TD{\dosingleempty\doTD}


\starttext

\TA[Big question]

\TB blabla
\TB blabla

\TB[Subquestion]

\TC
Blabla
\TC
Blabla

\TC[Subsubquestion With title]

Blabla
\TD Hello
\TD Pouet

\TC Hello

\TA Another question
\TA Another question

\stoptext
```

In this case the conversion does not work for subsubquestions and subsubsubquestions. Is there any option I used in these that interacts with the conversion ?

Comment: Replace the `prefixconversionset` key with `numberconversionset`.

Comment: It works with the MWE but not with something more along the lines of my real usage. I edit my answer to explain.

Comment: You need a comma after `numberconversionset=myconversion`, otherwise the space (which is inserted by the line break) after the argument is taken as part of it.

Comment: @Metafox This sounds like an answer.  Please post it in the answer section below.

Comment: It works indeed. How can I suggest to add it in the manual / the wiki ?

Comment: @A.Licari Just make an account on the Wiki and edit the page.

Comment: @Metafox maybe you should write a short answer so I could accept it and close the subject...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to end the last entry in your setups for the number conversion with a comma, because the line break is converted to a space and you pass `myconversion`  (with a space at the end of the name) to the `numberconversionset` key.

The correct way to write a setup is to end the last entry with a command

```
\setupenumeration
  [...]
  [
     numberconversionset=myconversion,
  ]
```

or put the right bracket after the last entry

```
\setupenumeration
  [...]
  [numberconversionset=myconversion]
```

In most cases there is no difference between both ways but when you use a older version of ConTeXt the first method doesn’t work for some commands (e.g. `\definepalet`).